# CORDOVA (PhoneGap) Android 4.2. "Unknown chromium error: -0"

Tags: android, cordova, android-fragments, cordova-3

After using Fragments instead of Activities for web view I've got Unknown chromium error: -0 on sending ajax requests. All domains whitelisted, cache = false.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, this error is due to the files,

```
The files probably are not dynamically loading correctly (no permission, looking in the wrong place).
The URl you have provided may be wrong.
```